# Regex SRV-record

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate a string to a regex (SRV-record)

When i test my RegEx on https://regex101.com/ it works without any problems:

"(?=^.{4,253}$)(([0-9]{1,10}[\s]{1,1}[0-9]{1,10}[\s]{1,1}((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-_^\s]{1,63}(?<!-)[.^\s]{0,1})+[a-zA-Z^\s]{2,63}[.^\s]{0,1}(?<![\s]))$)"gm

If i use this RegEx on my website it failed:

var pattern = new RegExp('(?=^.{4,253}$)(([0-9]{1,10}[\s]{1,1}[0-9]{1,10}[\s]{1,1}((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-_^\s]{1,63}(?<!-)[.^\s]{0,1})+[a-zA-Z^\s]{2,63}[.^\s]{0,1}(?<![\s]))$)');

if (!pattern.test(content)) alert ("failed")

I want a RegEx that works for SRV record so : weight port hostname

Where do i make the mistake ? I tested it with string: 100 100 test.nl.

Answer (score 0):

The regex works just fine - below is the proof.

```js
var pattern = new RegExp('(?=^.{4,253}$)(([0-9]{1,10}[\\s]{1,1}[0-9]{1,10}[\\s]{1,1}((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-_^\\s]{1,63}(?<!-)[.^\\s]{0,1})+[a-zA-Z^\\s]{2,63}[.^\\s]{0,1}(?<![\\s]))$)');

var content = "100 100 test.nl";
if (pattern.test(content)) alert ("passed");
```